# How to add a custom class for iframe by embed_oembed_html

Tags: php, functions, embed

I want to add a custom class for the embed_oembed_html filter (iframe).

NOTE 1: using str_replace will remove the anther classes so it's not useful.
NOTE 2: I need to add the custom class directly into the ifram tag not add the full iframe code into another tag like `<div>`.

Comment: "using str_replace will remove the anther classes so it's not useful" How are you doing str_replace? It's perfectly possible to add text with str_replace, not just replace it.

Comment: @JacobPeattie this is my code: $cache = str_replace("<iframe", '<iframe class="lazy-load"', $cache); and it's removed the anther classes

Comment: What does the original HTML look like? Update the original question with this information.

Comment: @JacobPeattie It's a blog post, My posts always have images, videos and iframes.

Comment: No, the normal embed HTML that's generated that you're trying to change.

Comment: @JacobPeattie sometimes videos youtube or Vimeo sometimes SoundCloud or WordPress (not a specific thing)

Comment: They're all going to have different HTML then, so you can't reliably add a class unless you have a condition for every type of embed that gets added with its own `str_replace()`. Why can't you use a wrapper?

Comment: @JacobPeattie because that I add a note that I can't use str_replace, I can't use a wrapper because I want to add lazy-load class and depending on the lazyload script that I used I must add the lazyload class for iframe tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just add a class because WordPress doesn't know anything about the existing classes or have any control over them, the way it does posts and nav items. This is because the HTML comes from the 3rd party raw.

So to replace the class you need to use `str_replace()`. You can use it to add a class, or any text, by doing it something like this:

```
$cache = str_replace( '<iframe class="existing-class ', '<iframe class="existing-class lazy-load ', $cache );
```

But that example will only work A. If the embed code is an iframe (which isn't always guaranteed) and B. `class=""` is the first attribute in the tag.

This means exact string to replace is going to differ based on the original HTML, which will be different for every provider. Inside your filter you'll need to check the source and do a different `str_replace()` to accommodate all the providers you need to support with this class:

```
function wpse_287229_embed_html( $cache, $url, $attr, $post_ID ) {
    if ( 
        strpos( $cache, 'youtube.com' ) !== false || 
        strpos( $cache, 'youtu.be' ) !== false 
    ) {
        $cache = str_replace( '<iframe ', '<iframe class="my-class" ', $cache ); // YouTube doesn't have a class on its iframe.
    }

    if ( strpos( $cache, 'soundcloud.com' ) !== false ) {
        // str_replace optimised for SoundCloud here.
    }

    // etc.

    return $cache;
}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'wpse_287229_embed_html', 10, 4 );
```